# How to change alignment of displayed equations in IPython Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, mathjax

I would like my MathJax displayed equations in IPython Notebook to be aligned at the left instead of centered. This is controlled by a core configuration option *displayAlign* in MathJax as described [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/hub.html).

I have tried to set this option in IPython Notebook by adding this to my *config.js* file

```js
MathJax.Hub.Config({ 
    displayAlign: "left"
});
```

but it doesn't have any effect.

How can I set MathJax core configuration options in IPython Notebook?

[Update] I have found one way that works: add the above configuration lines not to *config.js* but to *mathjaxutils.js*. In my case (Windows 8) this file is found here: `C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\IPython\html\static\notebook\js\mathjaxutils‌​.js`.  This is not a great solution though because it involves modifying a file that will presumably get overwritten the next time I update IPython.

[Update] The technique suggested by @Ian in the comments does work, but just one notebook at a time. To summarize, I created a file *my_css.css* whose content is

```
<script>
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        displayAlign: 'left'
    });
</script>
```

In the notebook, if I run this cell

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
css_file = 'my_css.css'
HTML(open(css_file, "r").read())
```

displayed equations do get left aligned, as desired.

However, I would like this to be the default for all my notebooks.  I tried adding this to my *custom.js*

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    displayAlign: 'left'
});
```

and for good measure added this to my *custom.css*

```
<script>
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        displayAlign: 'left'
    });
</script>
```

But neither has any effect. If there is a way to make this setting a default for all notebooks without modifying the core IPython files, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}`.  This does not exactly answer the question but it has the desired effect.  For example try:

```
$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{3}{2} = \frac{3}{4}
\end{align}
$
```

The above renders exactly the same as,

```
$$
\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{3}{2} = \frac{3}{4}
$$
```

except that it is left justified.

This approach has the added advantage that other alignments can be be added, as in:

```
$
\begin{align}
\dot{x} & = \sigma(y-x) \\
\dot{y} & = \rho x - y - xz \\
\dot{z} & = -\beta z + xy
\end{align}
$
```

This last code block is from [Motivating Examples](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Typesetting%20Equations.html#Motivating-Examples) in the Jupyter Notebook docs.

Other examples of aligning equations can be found here [Aligning several equations](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath#/Aligning_several_equations)

Comment: This has a lot of unintended side effects, and is a bit of a dangerous answer.  The purpose of `$` is signify the interpreting of LaTex, whereas `$$` signifies the start of a `LaTex Math Environment`.  There is a lot of differences between the two aside from just alignment.  Probably worth reading up on before just going with this answer.

Answer (score 17):

In Jupyter lab, I find that using a single `$` left aligns, whereas double `$` centers the equations

```
$
\begin{align}
c & = (0,\mu)+(a,b)\\
& =(a, b+\mu)
\end{align}
$
```

is left aligned whereas

```
$$
\begin{align}
c & = (0,\mu)+(a,b)\\
& =(a, b+\mu)
\end{align}
$$
```

is centered

Comment: While this may work in limited cases, the single quote is the LaTeX inline syntax which would cause all the maths to be displayed in inline mode.

Answer (score 2):

You could try including a css file. For example, [this set of notebooks](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/numerical-mooc/numerical-mooc/tree/master/lessons/01_phugoid/) pulls in [this css file](https://github.com/numerical-mooc/numerical-mooc/blob/master/styles/numericalmoocstyle.css) (see the final cell in the notebook) which does explicitly set the `displayAlign` tag, although it sets it to `center`.

Comment: Could by any chance give us an example as to how you included the `css`?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to modify only one notebook, you may write text below into your code cell and run it.

```
%%html
<style>
.MathJax_Display{ text-align: left!important; }
</style>
```

It modifies CSS of div element holding rendered LaTeX contents made by `$$ ... $$`