# Single spacing in Jupyter math mode

Tags: latex, markdown, jupyter

I'm trying to write out a series of math equations inline in Jupyter. I've written the following in my markdown:

> Solution:
>
> $x_1 = -8$
>
> $x_2 = 3$

The problem is that this displays much like it does in StackOverflow, with a space in between. Is there a way to display those as a single-spaced entity, rather than double-spaced? I'd rather them be left-aligned, so I don't want to double up the `$$`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change alignment of displayed equations in IPython Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353127/how-to-change-alignment-of-displayed-equations-in-ipython-notebook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `<br />` tag to insert a line break between the two equations (less space between lines):

```
    Solution:

    $x_1 = -8$ <br />
    $x_2 = 3$
```